# Xamarin Forms. Почему сбрасывается свойство IsEnabled при удалении из ListView?

Tags: listview, mvvm, observablecollection

Суть вот в чем.
Есть ListView, к которому в качестве ItemsSource прибиндена ObservableCollection из ViewModel, установленной в качестве BindingContext.

В каждой ячейке имеется Entry. И по умолчанию IsEnabled = false. 
При выборе ячейки все IsEnabled Entry ячеек устанавливаются в false, а выбранной ячейки устанавливается в true.
Все работает. 
Но. 
Когда удаляешь выбранную ячейку, из ObservableCollection, то по идее все должно быть нормально. Но нет. 
После удаления выбранный элемент коллекции удаляется, в ListView мы видим это. Но у следующего элемента (который по индексу теперь стал на место удаленного) в ListView Entry почему-то активно. Это при том, что в ObservableCollection все элементы имеют свойство false.

Даже если после удаления очищать ListView и заменять ItemsSource на пустую ObservableCollection. А затем снова прибиндить к ItemsSource нужную ObservableCollection, то вообще все Entry становятся активны (Хотя в самой коллекции все свойства IsEnabled = false). 
Это происходит до тех пор, пока вручную(тапом) не выберешь в ListView каждый элемент с активным Entry.

Что делать? Это происходит именно после удаления. 
Но, например, когда добавляешь новый элемент, - все работает как нужно. Можно даже просто в ObservableCollection установить все значения Entry IsEnabled каждой ячейки в false и в ListView все правильно отразится. Все будут неактивны, до тех пор пока не выберешь какой-то элемент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, разобрался с этой проблемой.

Нужно всегда устанавливать SelectedItem. Даже, когда очевидно это не совсем нужно. То есть, например, вы добавляете новый элемент в коллекцию прибинденную к ItemsSource ListView, все равно нужно устанавливать SelectedItem, даже если вы сразу после этого все значения Entry IsEnabled в коллекции ставите на false.

Ну а при удалении тоже нужно устанавливать SelectedItem. Например, при удалении последнего в списке, устанавливать на предыдущий, а при удалении не последнего на следующий. И только когда в коллекции нет членов, то SelectedItem = null.

И да, нужно помнить, что у SelectedItem Mode="TwoWay" должен быть.